# How to print individual values from a set in python

Tags: python

i have a set with the following output
set(['SCD-3392', 'SCD-3547', 'SCD-3507'])

I am trying to export this into a csv file. It gets printed the same way instead i want it to only display as

```
SCD-3392
SCD-3547
SCD-3507
```

Comment: So what have you tried, what didn't work? Sets can be iterated over, so a simple loop should do. Sets do *not* have a specific order however.

Comment: for obj in coll:
        print(obj)

Yep, its that easy

Comment: please search in SO for similar questions before posting a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> for item in set(['SCD-3392', 'SCD-3547', 'SCD-3507']):
...    print(item)
... 
SCD-3392
SCD-3547
SCD-3507
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print "\n".join(set(['SCD-3392', 'SCD-3547', 'SCD-3507']))
```